# VirtualHost no sirve en otros dispositivos dentro de la misma red

Tags: xampp, localhost, virtualhost

La cosa es asi, e hecho un virtual host en xampp (windows), con el server name 'cona.sys' y asi acceder al proyecto que tengo ahi. Normal, desde el pc donde corro el xampp me da acceso solo poniendo "http://cona.sys/", pero cuando lo pongo lo mismo en mi movil u otra pc (en la misma red), no funciona, tira error, no se puede acceder al sitio...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si pongo la ip del pc (192.168.1.12, ip fija) donde corro el xampp entra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto tengo en el archivo "httpd-vhosts.conf" en la parte final

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\CONASYS\public"
ServerName cona.sys
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\CONASYS\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

y esto en el archivo "hosts" en la parte final

```
192.168.1.12    cona.sys
```

y esto en archivo "httpd-xampp.conf" de configuaracion del apache (que es lo que permite el acceso remoto tenia entendio, corríjanme)
sacado de: [este post que me facilitaron](https://nosololinux.es/permitir-acceso-a-xampp-desde-cualquier-pc/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

soy novato en esto, y pues quiero ingresar desde mi celular u otra pc al proyecto usando  pues "cona.sys"-"http://cona.sys/", èr este detalle del server name del vhost n se como solucionarlo, saludos y gracias

Comment: usa laragon, es mas facil de configurar

Answer (score 1):

los archivos hosts sólo son válidos en los dispositivos donde estan alojados, por eso en tu pc si funciona, así que debes investigar como modificar tu archivo hosts de tu android para poder asignarle la ip a al dominio.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score 1):

los [nombres de dominio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_nombres_de_dominio) (cona.sys) no son asignados por ningun equipo cliente, son asignados desde un servidor DNS (Domain name server o servidor de nombre de dominios), en tu caso especifico lo mas probable es que ese servidor se encuentre alojado en el router del proveedor que te da el servicio de internet, no todos son configurables, pero el problema que vas a tener es que cada vez que una PC enciende el router puede asignarle una direccion IP diferente a la que tenia anteriormente, haciendo que todo lo que hagas en el DNS sea inutil

Para resolverlo tienes que hacer 2 cosas:

Primero: configurar el [servidor DHCP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_configuraci%C3%B3n_din%C3%A1mica_de_host) para que la computadora que funcione como servidor web siempre obtenga la misma [direccion IPV4](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) (igual posiblemente el router en tu caso), lo mejor es enlazar la direccion IP con la [direccion MAC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_MAC) de la tarjeta de red

Segundo: configurar en el servidor DNS un nuevo [registro tipo A](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_CNAME), alli pones el nombre que le quieres asignar al servidor y la direccion IP que le diste en el servidor DHCP

Todo esto suponiendo que tu router lo soporte (otra vez no todos los routers caseros lo soportan) y definitivamente cada router es distinto asi que tendras que revisar las instrucciones especificas con el manual de usuario de tu router

Si el router no lo soporta, tendras que armar un servidor DNS para asignar los nombres, ademas del servidor web que ya tienes, pero ambos pueden correr en la misma computadora..

Comment: gracias, ahora me queda un poco mas claro el tema, crei que era alguna configuracion del xampp